# Unity terrain collider intermittently missing collisions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, terrain, mesh-collider

I am experimenting with the terrain tools. The app has a cube (0.2x0.2x0.05) that flies around representing a quadcopter. It has a collider (not set as trigger) and rigidbody. It is controlled by addforce() etc - ie its position and rotation are not changed directly.

It works quite reliably in scenery constructed from primitives (cubes, spheres etc).

I am now trying out the Unity terrain tools package (I'm using editor 2019.3) and have a simple test terrain (500x500m) with rock, scree and sand layers.

What I find is that sometimes when flying it directly into the terrain just to check what happens, it goes straight through. Often it collides OK, but not always, maybe 50:50.

The FixedUpdate() rate is the standard 20mS.

I'm not sure if there is any step I have missed? I am just using all default settings on the terrain. It has the standard mesh collider. It isn't set up just as a trigger or anything (anyway, mostly it works OK).

Is this something I've done / not done, or is this a known issue - is there a workaround?

STOP PRESS: Testing still in progress, but have a feeling this may be to do with the collision type selected in the rigidbody - see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Testing still in progress, but it strongly appears this is be to do with the collision type selected in the rigidbody. Default is discrete, but there is information in the Unity docs that with fast moving bodies, it may be necessary to use continuous (at some CPU cost) to avoid missing some collisions.

The problem has not happened since the type was changed to continuous.
The quadcopter is after all, quite a fast moving body, up to 150 kph, and small.